# How can I send an object from a controller to a view Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to send the result of the controller to the view 
The result is in json format
What should I add to the controller so I can send the object to the view

```
  while (rs.next()) {
            Long issuenum = rs.getLong("issuenum");
            String assignee = rs.getString("assignee");
            String summary = rs.getString("summary");
            Date created = rs.getDate("created");
            Date resolutiondate = rs.getDate("resolutiondate");
            ResolvedTickets RS = new ResolvedTickets(rs.getLong("issuenum"), rs.getString("assignee"), rs.getString("summary"), rs.getDate("created"), rs.getDate("resolutiondate"));
            res.add(RS);
        }

        st.close();


        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelAndView is an object that holds both the model and view. The handler returns the ModelAndView object and DispatcherServlet resolves the view using View Resolvers and View.

The View is an object which contains view name in the form of the String and model is a map to add multiple objects.

In the below example 'employeeDetails' is the view name.

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("employeeDetails");
model.addObject("employeeObj", new EmployeeBean(123));
model.addObject("msg", "Employee information.");
return model;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to access object in view :

1) ModelAndView
   Here you can directly add modelAndView.addObject("objectName", Object);
   You can acces it on page by following
   ${objectName}

Same For Model

2) If you want object in json format for that you have to convert object into json 
   first by using ObjectMapper in spring-mvc and then you can catch that json 
   string in view page as done method 1.

Example :

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = jsonMapper.toJson(yourObject);
mav.addObject("json",json);
And on view page you can acces it inside javascript :

<script>
var jsonString = ${json};
/* Here you can play with json now */
</script>
```